# Why would the cabin crew spray the cabin before landing?

Tags: airline-operations, flight-attendant

Once when I was on a plane that was about to land, the cabin crew came around and they were spraying these small canisters. I've been on many flights but it was that particular flight where they did the spray. Can someone please tell me what those spray's are?

Comment: Where were you flying from and to?

Comment: It's bug spray. http://www.cntraveler.com/stories/2016-02-19/why-flight-attendants-walk-airplane-aisles-with-bug-spray. Also here: https://www.transportation.gov/office-policy/aviation-policy/aircraft-disinsection-requirements

Comment: Maybe the passengers just smelled bad...

Comment: .....chemtrails (dun, dun, DUNNNN.......)

Comment: They spray to help disinfect and clean the cabin in case when it takes off it's not carrying a sickness on board.

Comment: They normally announce over the PA systems before spraying them, you should listen to them more.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The sprays are (usually) insecticides used to prevent the spread of invasive species and diseases.

> The process of ‘disinsection’ is required under the International Health Regulations of the World Health Organization (WHO) on flights to and from certain destinations to prevent infectious and contagious diseases carried by insects and other volatile bodies. Rules established by the International Civil Aviation Organization (ICAO) require that disinsection does not injure or cause discomfort to passengers or crew. These rules permit the use of certain insecticides, which have the approval of and are recommended by the WHO based on their effectiveness and safety.

From the [US dept. of Transportation](https://www.transportation.gov/office-policy/aviation-policy/aircraft-disinsection-requirements)

Comment: +1. I've been on flights recently where insecticide was sprayed even though the countries involved were not on the US Department of Transportation list you linked, so either the list is incomplete or airlines are spraying even where it is not required.

Comment: Why immediately before landing, rather than immediately after take-off?

Comment: @ZachLipton what country? If you read further down it says some countries require it on all flights from all countries that have zika.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe you could probably ask that as a separate se question but it would make sense to do it while on the ground in the unlikely event that someone had a bad reaction to the spray.

Comment: Air Namibia did that in the 90's on their flights between Frankfurt/Windhuk with a 747-200SP. I thought as child, or where told, that it was against air-sickness. Thinking about malaria and other possible diseases in northern Namibia this make now more sense :)

Comment: Inbound flights to NZ used to be sprayed (after landing and before disembarkation). I don't know if they still are.

Comment: @Notts90 They sprayed on a flight from Morocco to Portugal not long ago. Also one from Dubai to or from South Africa, I don't remember which direction it was.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Why not both for extra thoroughness?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Maybe so that they don't have to breathe the insecticides over the flight duration?

Comment: I guessed it was to prevent people breathing insecticides for the whole flight, and to allow for the possibility that someone has a reaction, but it'd be nice to see something official in the answer.

Comment: @Notts90: Well, then, why not spray just _before_ takeoff, so that anyone having a reaction can be jettisoned immediately?

Comment: @Sean you’d also have to find a and jettison their hold luggage which could take a while and cause delays. Do it at the destination and their luggage is coming off regardless.

Answer (score 5):

I was on an extremely long flight once, and the cabin crew walked up the aisles around the halfway point spraying canisters (about two in each hand) of what they said were disinfectants, required by the World Health Organization because we had so many people cooped up in a limited-air-exchange environment for so long.  The idea as explained was to prevent passenger-to-passenger disease transmission.

However, on looking it up, I find [the WHO's page](http://www.who.int/ith/mode_of_travel/aircraft_disinsection/en/) refer to disinfection of aircraft as being primarily about killing insects, so there may have been an error in communication.  See also [this USA Today article](http://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/columnist/mcgee/2015/05/13/disinsection-airplane-pesticide-spraying/27177835/) for more information.